# CodeIgniter htaccess 403

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm working with CodeIgniter. I would like to delete the index.php part from the url.
I'm using CentOS.

My Apache config is:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My files are located in:
/var/www/html/project/site/
Then the url is:
example.com/project/site/

My htaccess is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

That comes from the official wiki.

I have created a Site.php controller with a Site class.
If I go to example.com/project/site/site it loads the pages, however the CSS and img files (located in views/template/) don't load because of a 403 permission denied error.

However, if I change AllowOverride All in AllowOverride None and then I go to:
example.com/project/site/index.php/site

It works, so the permission on the files are ok.

By the way, this is my config.php file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://ipserver/project/site/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

**SOLUTION**

Adding Satisfy Any in the config httpd file seems to work.

Comment: How are you referring to your assets? Whats the path for your assets?

Comment: In views I've a template folder, with css, js and other subfolder. Also I've pages, where there is the main html of the pages. In this pages, I put this:
<?php echo $base_url; ?>/images/bg/1.jpg
Which comes from this: $data['base_url'] = base_url('/application/views/template/');

Of corse, this is the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following step:

1. Change the config file like this:

   $config['index_page'] = '';
   $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
2. Use the following .htaccess:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]`

Note: .htaccess vary depending on server. I some server (e.g.: Godaddy) need to use the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Source link: https://www.linkedin.com/groups/109912/109912-5948862618142785540

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I have still 403 errors. Should I put che htaccess in the root of the framework or in the root of the server?
I've a dedicated server

Comment: @Dray This is the result: http://37.187.6.125/project/fattoriabesana/frame/ with that htaccess in the root of the framework

By the way, this is the method:
http://37.187.6.125/project/fattoriabesana/frame/site

And this is another page:
http://37.187.6.125/project/fattoriabesana/frame/site/shop
As you can see, there is a 403 problem on the files in the template dir

Comment: @ArifulIslam As written in the main post, I added Satisfy Any in the config httpd file and it seems to work